# Can the last two player heal with beer when Ghost Town is in play?

Tags: bang, bang-high-noon

There are only two players left in the game, say an Outlaw and the Sheriff. The Sheriff reveals Ghost Town at the beginning of his turn. Can he heal himself with a Beer card?

I don't think he can, but we had a very adamant player among ourselves who said this was possible, so I would like to ask your opinions.

Edit: Ghost Town is a card from the High Noon expansion with the following ability: *During their turns, eliminated players return to the game as ghost. They draw 3 cards instead of 2, and cannot die. At the end of their turn, they are eliminated again.*

Edit-2: I'm adding some possible interpretations to the rules:

- **Cannot heal**: Since ghosts are not *alive* during the Sheriff's turn, the Beer card has no effect due to there being only 2 players in the game.
- **Can heal**: Other players do come back during the Ghost Town effect (with zero life?) so the Sheriff is allowed to heal himself with the Beer card. This would also help the remaining 2 players survive the incoming bullets from the revived ghosts.
- **Can heal, but only to save himself during a ghost's turn**: During a ghost's turn there are 3 players in the game so if the Sheriff gets killed, he can still save himself with a beer card.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, that this is from the High Noon expansion. Ghost town - *During their turns, eliminated players return to the game as ghost. They draw 3 cards instead of 2, and cannot die. At the end of their turn, they are eliminated again.*

Comment: I added some possible interpretations. I think in this particular scenario ghosts can heal themselves with Beer since there are 3 players in the game (Sheriff, Outlaw and the ghost). However the Sheriff (and also the Outlaw) cannot heal himself with the Beer card in his own turn because there are only 2 players in the game (Sheriff and Outlaw).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question revolved around the following limitation:

> *Beer* has **no effect** if there are only **2 players** left in the game; in other words, if you play a *Beer* you do not gain any life point.

(Emphasis in original.)

As such, it comes down to the number of players left in the game. According to *Ghost Town*, and reinforced by this [FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/10570/highnoon-faq-engpdf), each ghost is in play until the end of their turn, to the point that they can even be considered winners and can cause the Renegade to lose.

As such,

- On the Sheriff's turn, there are two players left in the game. The Sheriff can't use a *Beer*.
- On the "live" Outlaw's turn, there are two players left in the game. The Sheriff can't use a *Beer*.
- On a ghost's turn, there are three players left in the game. The Sheriff can use a *Beer* on the ghost's turn (in reaction to a lethal hit).